# How to install python-docx for Python3

Tags: python3

This seems a basic question, but I cannot find the answer.
Running Mint 19.1
I have installed python-docx with

```
sudo pip install python-docx
```

If I run

```
python doctest.py
```

it runs python 2.7.15 and works fine, but if I run

```
python3 doctest.py
```

it runs python 3.6.7 and fails with
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
I have also run

```
sudo pip install --pre python-docx
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

It looks like I have python-docx installed for 2.7 but not for 3. How do I do it?
I have asked this question on the github issues page but got no replies.
Thanks
Mick

Answer (score 1):

I think I have now solved it. 
Needed pip3 to install it, pip3 didn't seem to work, so I removed pip3, reinstalled it, then installed python-docx again and it all seems fine now.
Don't understand why, but it works :)